# Django tracking app?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there an application for django which tracks CRUD for objects inside a project?

Comment: What sort of tracking are you after? The Django admin already shows you which objects have been created/edited/deleted.

Comment: I want to track activity within the website, which user has updated/created/deleted a certain object.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an audit trail for model changes, you could start with [AuditTrail](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AuditTrail). It's a little rough around the edges but I'm not aware of anything else in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by using [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) provided by Django.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [django-reversion](http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/).

It keeps a detailed log of who did what that is viewable from the admin.  It also lets you go back and see any older version, and also to restore deleted versions of models.  It includes a middleware component to let any model change be logged, even if it wasn't done by the admin tool.  It has pretty decent documetnation as well.

Comment: Actually something like this is what i'm looking for

http://github.com/uggedal/django-activitystreams

But this project hasn't started yet. Is this the first or are there more?